# After limited dissolve how to reduce some unnecessary edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, edges, blenderkit

The image was imported from SketchUp, please how can I manually remove those unnecessary edges[image][image]

Comment: manually? delete those edges, fill new face and cut with Knife

Comment: It's not possible to get rid of these edges